# Transferring website

Tags: web, hosting

I have made some changes to a site and need to re-host it as the current host is ceasing to exist.  My client has received the following from the current host:

"The best thing to tell them is that, due to the fact that we are withdrawing our service completely, we would look to fully transfer the web site address across to them rather than just "point" the web address at them. If you can forward this Email to them and ask them to 
confirm their "IPS tag" (they'll know what that is), I can then arrange for it to be transferred as and when they confirm it's all ready to go."

Can anyone help me out here as i'm not too sure what they mean, nor do I know what an IPS tag is? ?

Answer (score 3):

an IPSTAG is a .uk only designation of the domain's registrar. basically, the webhost is asking you to transfer the domain name registration away from them to a new provider.

i would suggest you (or your client) find a new registrar, get their IPSTAG, and then send that to your old host, who will then be able to initiate the change.

once the IPSTAG has been updated (you can check WHOIS information for that), then your new registrar will be able to get the domain name (and thus the old host will have relinquished "control" of it)

here's an example from amazon.co.uk's WHOIS:

```
Domain name:
    amazon.co.uk

Registrant:
    Amazon Europe Holding Technologies SCS

Registrant type:
    Unknown

Registrant's address:
    65 boulevard G-D. Charlotte
    Luxembourg City
    Luxembourg
    LU-1311
    LU

Registrar:
    Amazon.com [Tag = AMAZON-COM]
```

the IPSTAG in this case is "AMAZON-COM"

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search turns up

> Each Domain Name registration agent is identified by a unique IPSTAG assigned by the UK Governing body for UK Domain Names, Nominet. If you want to move a UK domain name to another Internet Service Provider, you will need to know the Tag Name of your new ISP.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [link](http://transferdomains.co.uk/index.php?cat=26) for what an IPS tag is. It's essentially an identifier for your domain registration agent. To quote:

> An IPS TAG allows Nominet to
>   administer use of their automated
>   domain name registration system and
>   associated services. The IPS-TAG is a
>   unique sequence of letters and/or
>   numbers. You need to be able to tell
>   Nominet your registration agent's tag
>   to be able to change your registration
>   agent.